# Best way to update React DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and I want to build a Spotify clone which lets me control my playback. Therefore I'm fetching the API every second to get the current data.

So far everything works just fine but I'm asking myself what would be the best way to display the current data in the browser.
Right now I'm using a useState for the current data which rerenders my code including the DOM and displays the data every time I set the useState. As this happens every second I have my concern if this is performant.

Are there any best practices or concepts I can use? I was thinking about setting the current data via innerHTML as with that I could avoid rerendering my component every second.

Thanks for every answer!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: using `innerHTML` is **extremely wrong** when using React. **only** React is in charge of the DOM and so it knows everything since it's managed by it. If you manipulate the DOM outside of it, then you are not using React at all, and ruin all the good things it brings to the table

Comment: Fetching data is done inside `useEffect` where you set the state only on the first render (or maybe if some prop has changed, for example, filters/pagination)

Comment: I do start the fetching interval in useEffect but I‘m concerned on how to tell the DOM to display the current data from the latest interval. I have to update the DOM every second but want to do so in a performant way.